# Google Mobile Vision not detecting any faces from a CIImage

Tags: ios, google-api, swift4, google-contacts-api, google-vision

I am trying to use the Google Mobile Vision API to detect when a user smiles from the camera feed. The problem I have is that the Google Mobile Vision API is not detecting any faces while apple's vision api immediately recognizes and tracks any face that I test my app with. I am using `func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) { }` to detect when a user is smiling. Apple's Vision API seems to work fine but Google's API does not detect any faces. How would I fix my code to get Google's API to work as well? What am I doing wrong?

My Code...

```
    var options = [GMVDetectorFaceTrackingEnabled: true, GMVDetectorFaceLandmarkType: GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all.rawValue, GMVDetectorFaceMinSize: 0.15] as [String : Any]

 var GfaceDetector = GMVDetector.init(ofType: GMVDetectorTypeFace, options: options)

extension ViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {



func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

    let attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)
    let ciImage1 = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!, options: attachments as! [String : Any]?)
    let Gimage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage1)
        var Gfaces = GfaceDetector?.features(in: Gimage, options: nil) as? [GMVFaceFeature]


    let options: [String : Any] = [CIDetectorImageOrientation: exifOrientation(orientation: UIDevice.current.orientation),
                                   CIDetectorSmile: true,
                                   CIDetectorEyeBlink: true]
    let allFeatures = faceDetector?.features(in: ciImage1, options: options)

    let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)
    let cleanAperture = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture(formatDescription!, false)

    var smilingProb = CGFloat()


    guard let features = allFeatures else { return }


    print("GFace \(Gfaces?.count)")
    //THE PRINT ABOVE RETURNS 0
    //MARK: ------ Google System Setup

       for face: GMVFaceFeature in Gfaces! {
        print("Google1")

        if face.hasSmilingProbability {
            print("Google \(face.smilingProbability)")
            smilingProb = face.smilingProbability
        }
    }

    for feature in features {
        if let faceFeature = feature as? CIFaceFeature {
            let faceRect = calculateFaceRect(facePosition: faceFeature.mouthPosition, faceBounds: faceFeature.bounds, clearAperture: cleanAperture)
            let featureDetails = ["has smile: \(faceFeature.hasSmile), \(smilingProb)",
                "has closed left eye: \(faceFeature.leftEyeClosed)",
                "has closed right eye: \(faceFeature.rightEyeClosed)"]

            update(with: faceRect, text: featureDetails.joined(separator: "\n"))
        }
    }

    if features.count == 0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.detailsView.alpha = 0.0
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I copied and pasted the Google Mobile Vision Detection Code into another app and it worked. The difference was that instead of constantly receiving frames, the app had only one image to analyze. Could this have something to do with how often I send a request or the format/quality of the CIImage?

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I have identified an issue with how my app works. It seems that the image that the API is receiving is not upright or inline with the orientation of the phone. For example if I hold my phone up in front of my face (in normal portrait mode) the image is rotated 90 degrees anti clockwise. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening as the live camera preview is normal. The Google Docs say...

> The face detector expects images and the faces in them to be in an upright orientation. If you need to rotate the image, pass in orientation information in the dictionary options with GMVDetectorImageOrientation key. The detector will rotate the images for you based on the orientation value.

**New Question:** (I believe the answer to either one of these questions will solve my problem)

A: How would I use the GMVImageDetectorImageOrientation key to set the orientation right?

B: How would I rotate the UIImage 90 degrees clockwise (NOT THE UIIMAGEVIEW)?

**THIRD UPDATE**

I have successfully rotated the image right side up but Google Mobile Vision is still not detecting any faces, the image is a bit distorted but I do not think the amount of distortion is affecting Google Mobile Vision's response. So...

**How would I use the GMVImageDetectorImageOrientation key to set the orientation right?**

**ANY HELP/RESPONSE IS APPRECIATED.**